# How to use react hooks to pass a state from child component to the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the parent component as below. Here I want to set the setLoading function  inside the child component
loading.

```
const ReportRechargeDetail = React.memo(() => {
  const [selectedDates, setSelectedDates] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
return (
    <>
       <Row className="header-wrapper">
        <div>
          Select date range to proceed : <Space />
          <RangePicker
            format="YYYY-MM-DD"
            onChange={onChange}
            disabled={loading}
            onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
            disabledDate={(currentDate) => currentDate.isAfter(moment())}

          />

        </div>
      </Row>
      { selectedDates ? (
        <Row className="header-wrapper">
          <div>
            <PrimeButton
              buttonName={"Download report"}
              onClick={onClickHeaderButton}
            />
          </div>
        </Row>
      ) : (<div></div>)
      }
      <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={callback} type="card">
        <TabPane tab="IN APP" key="1">
          <GenerateReport
            columns={columns}
            reportType={"recharge-info/in-app"}
            reportName={"Recharge Details "}
            breadcrumbName={"RECHARGED_DETAILED_REPORT"}
            fileDownloadUrl={""}
            selectedDateRange={selectedDates}
            isOpen={isOpen}
            isLoadingCallBack={setLoading}
          />
        </TabPane>
        <TabPane tab="BALANCE" key="2">
          <GenerateReport
            columns={columns}
            reportType={"recharge-info/online"}
            reportName={"Recharge Details "}
            breadcrumbName={"RECHARGED_DETAILED_REPORT"}
            fileDownloadUrl={"Recharge"}
            selectedDateRange={selectedDates}
            isOpen={isOpen}
          />
        </TabPane>
      </Tabs>

    </>
  );
});

export default ReportRechargeDetail;
```

child component as below. But I am getting an error , Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```
const GenerateReport = React.memo(
    ({
        columns,
        reportType,
        reportName,
        breadcrumbName,
        fileDownloadUrl,
        downloadReport,
        downloadReportName,
        selectedDateRange,
        isOpen,
        isLoadingCallBack
    }) => {
        const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
        //const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
        const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
        const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(10);
        const [selectedDates, setSelectedDates] = useState(selectedDateRange);
        const [performedActionList, setPerformedActionList] = useState([]);
        const [totalCount, SetTotalCount] = useState(0);
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
        const [requiredTotal, setRequiredTotal] = useState(true);
        const dispatch = useDispatch();

 const getRecurrentData = (dateStrings) => {
            isLoadingCallBack(true);
            setLoading(true);
            setShow(true);
 });
        };

return (
            <>
                {show ? (
                    <Spin spinning={loading}>
                        <ViewBoxBody
                            loading={loading}
                            showPrimaryButton={false}
                            columns={columns}
                            filterSearchBar={false}
                            dataSource={performedActionList}
                            onPaginationClick={onPaginationClick}
                            currentPage={pageNumber}
                            totalDataCount={totalCount}
                            pageSize={pageSize}
                            showSizeChanger={true}
                            onShowSizeChange={(curent, size) => setPageSize(size)}
                            hideOnSinglePage={false}
                            showTotal={(total) => {
                                return `Total ${total} items`;
                            }}
                        />
                        <ViewBoxFooter

                            onPaginationClick={onPaginationClick}
                            currentPage={pageNumber}
                            totalDataCount={totalCount}
                            pageSize={pageSize}
                            showSizeChanger={true}
                            onShowSizeChange={(curent, size) => setPageSize(size)}
                            hideOnSinglePage={false}
                            showTotal={(total) => {
                                return `Total ${total} items`;
                            }}
                        />
                    </Spin>
                ) : (
                    <div></div>
                )}
            </>
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `setLoading` to your child component, wrap the hook call inside a user-defined method in your parent component.

```
...
const toggleLoading = (value) => {
  setLoading(value)
}
...
return ...
```

and use that method in the child component's props `isLoadingCallBack={toggleLoading}`. Depending on the complexity, it would make sense to wrap the parent state in a Context [1] so that you can access the values/setters anywhere in the child tree.

[1] https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

This error has 3 causes as listed in the error description

> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

let's take number 2 first to make sure we are following the rules of hooks

Your code looks fine, but let's take a small piece of working code and we are sure about it to try it in your environment https://codesandbox.io/s/little-monad-0jo71?file=/src/App.js try the example here and put it in a separate page/route if it works then the problem will be with your code and we will investigate more in it.

**now number 1**

> You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as
> React DOM)

**Suggested Solution:**

Double-check your react and react-dom versions

**now number 3**

> You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

**Suggested Solution:**

Try the solutions in this issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991